# Extracting file content between tags for each file in a directory to a new location

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

let us say i have a file called "foo1.txt,v" in directory location1/bar containing my desired text enclosed in a starting tag and a ending tag

```
@@
text
@<content> 
@
```

my directory bar contains "foo1.txt,v" "foo2.txt,v"......."fooN.txt,v"

i want to get content between the tags @@\ntext\n@ and \n@\n from each file and save it in
location2/bar with filename foo1.txt foo2.txt ...... fooN.txt

i.e. duplicate the folder structure to another location while removing the ",v" from filename where the new file contains only the dear text

Answer (score 1):

This awk one-liner should do:

```
 awk '/^@@/{p=1;next}/^@$/{p=0}p{f=FILENAME;sub(/,v$/,"",f);print > "/loc2/bar/"f}' loc1/foo/*
```

a little test:

```
kent@7pLaptop:/tmp/test/foo$ head *
@@text@
xxx
@

==> foo2.txt,v <==
@@text@
yyy
@
kent@7pLaptop:/tmp/test/foo$ ls -l /tmp/test/bar 
total 0
kent@7pLaptop:/tmp/test/foo$ awk '/^@@/{p=1;next}/^@$/{p=0}p{f=FILENAME;sub(/,v$/,"",f);print > "/tmp/test/bar/"f}' *
kent@7pLaptop:/tmp/test/foo$ head /tmp/test/bar/*
==> /tmp/test/bar/foo1.txt <==
xxx

==> /tmp/test/bar/foo2.txt <==
yyy
kent@7pLaptop:/tmp/test/foo$
```

Comment: can you please explain the regex a bit please

Comment: @Mohit well there is not much to be explained. there were two regexs, `/^@@/` means lines starting with two `@`. `/^@$/` means the line has only one char: `@`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script:

```
cd /path/to/location1/..

mkdir -p location2/bar

for file in location1/bar/*.txt,v
do
    name=${file##*/}
    sed -n '/^@@/{:a;n;/^@/!{p;ba};q0}' $file > location2/bar/${name%,v}
done
```

Comment: can you please explain the regex a bit please

Comment: for each line starting with @@ (/^@@/), print the first line and load a new line (n) than for each line that doesn not start with @ (/^@/!) , print it (p) and goto (restart) at new line load earlier (ba -> :a), if not quit (q0) sed (so after the first line starting with @

Answer (score 0):

Without sed or awk it is somewhat bigger:

```
#!/bin/bash

FROM="/location1/foo" ; cd "$FROM"         #goto the originating directory
DEST="/location2/bar" ; mkdir -p "$DEST"   #create a destination directory 

#with the `for` loop we visit each file in the FROM directory.
for FILE in *.txt,v 
do
    # we start reading the FILE here given by the 'for' loop 
    # line by line until there is no more to read. 
    while read LINE; do

        #TAG is a flag we unset if the line we read is "@" (end tag).
        [ "$LINE" = "@"        ] && TAG=""

        #if TAG is set,append the line to the destination file without the ,v
        [ "$TAG"               ] && echo "$LINE" >> "$DEST/${FILE%,v}"

        #Set TAG if the first two characters of the line is "@@" (start tag).
        [ "${LINE:0:2}" = "@@" ] && TAG="X"

    done < "$FILE" #<-- this is where 'while read LINE' gets input
    TAG=""         #<-- unset TAG, a missing end-tag could have left it "set"
done
```

Comment: can you please provide a little explaination

Comment: I added comments to the source, hope you like it :-)